# Linux equivalent command for "open" command on Mac/Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, mac, command-line

Coming from Mac OS X, you can type:

```
$ open yourfilehere.txt
```

and your file will open just as if you had opened it from Finder.

---

On Windows, one can type:

```
> start yourfilehere.txt
```

and it will open just as if you had opened it from Explorer.

---

On Ubuntu, I'd like to be able to open files in the same manner in GNOME. What's the command?

Comment: In little related I found this little gem to open Finder in a certain path (not current path necessarily): open -a Finder . or open -a Finder /your/path/here

Comment: I just saw that *On Windows, this is the `start` program. On OS X, this is the `open` program. On Ubuntu Linux, this is the `see` program.* in book [automate-the-boring-stuff-with-python](http://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter15/), but I didn't get any info about `see` command from Google.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`xdg-open` is what you're looking for.

You might like this snippet I put in my `.bashrc` files so that whether I'm using cygwin on Windows, Linux, or OSX, I can use either the start or the open commands and they work great:

```
case "$OSTYPE" in
   cygwin*)
      alias open="cmd /c start"
      ;;
   linux*)
      alias start="xdg-open"
      alias open="xdg-open"
      ;;
   darwin*)
      alias start="open"
      ;;
esac
```

Good comments, `xdg-open` is indeed a better option than `gnome-open` as explained below. I updated my personal scripts a while ago, but forgot to update this answer.

WARNING: This will override the functionality of both `openvt` (virtual terminal) and `start` from init.

Comment: That BASH script is a great idea.

Comment: cygwin: try "cygstart"

Comment: gnome-open is GNOME-specific. xdg-open is available on all Freedesktop.org compliant distros.

Comment: @DougHarris, +1. `cygstart` may be further preferable, as in Emacs bookmarks, it allows one to continue using Emacs. With `start`, my Emacs is frozen.

Comment: Then, start is nice if you don't want to rely on Cygwin being available. `start ""` or `"start \"\""` just worked for me. (Set of quotes "" prevents Emacs hanging on process.)

Comment: "xdg-open" does not support launching executable programs for safety - use "exec" for them.

Comment: I wonder if this script could be extended to detect when it's an executable program, and use exec for those?

Answer (score 37):

```
xdg-open xyz.bar
```

will open `xyz.bar` (a file or URL) in any freedesktop-compatible environment via the application registered for `xyz.bar`'s type.  See also the [man page for xdg-open](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-open.html).

In practice this should then call `kde-open`, `gnome-open`, `exo-open` or possibly even `open`, depending on the current desktop environment (KDE, Gnome, XFCE, OS X).

Comment: also works. What's the difference between `xdg-open` and `gnome-open` ?

Comment: well, xdg-open was developed by the freedesktop.org folks which claim to create the "standard", while gnome-open was developed by the gnome folks .. which you only get when you install gnome. i personally like the freedesktop.org stuff more.

Comment: Indeed, xdg-open is the right answer here. gnome-open is specific to desktops that have GNOME installed. xdg-open will be available on any freedesktop-compliant system.

Comment: "xdg-open will be available on any freedesktop-compliant system" means, in practice, that no matter whether you are using GNOME, KDE, Xfce, or any other environment, `xdg-open` will do the _Right Thing_, using the file-type-to-program mapping of the running environment.

Comment: It's *almost* equivalent to Mac's "open" command, but not quite — I'm finding (under Ubuntu 14 at least) that when I use it on a directory, the directory opens in the background.  I'd rather it bring the freshly opened window to the front.  Any way to make it do that?  (Forgive me, I'm a total Linux noob.)

Answer (score 11):

You can even write a small wrapper around gnome-open to open multiple files with one command:

```
for i in $*
do
    gnome-open "$i"
done
```

Put this into a shell script named open and

```
open *.c
```

will open all c files in the current directory.

Comment: Useful script, but you'll want to replace $* with "$@" (including the quotes) to properly handle filenames with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `gnome-open` command in your Terminal.
Once in the directory which you want to open an OS window of, type in the Terminal:

```
gnome-open .
```

This will open a window showing what is in this folder.
Similarly, you can specify a subfolder located in this directory by substituting the `.` by the name of the subfolder.

Note that if `gnome-open` doesn't work, it may just need to be installed. You can do so using Synaptic (`sudo apt-get update` and then
`sudo apt-get install synaptic` in your terminal, very convinient when installing package because it installs all the dependencies properly) or directly install Gnome Shell in your Terminal: `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`

Answer (score -1):

Enter this into the terminal: `./yourfile`

`yourfile` is the name of the file you want to open or run. You can also use this command to run bash scripts. (Remember to enter the file extension!)

> `gnome-open` is what you're looking for.

Another quote from another poster.