# Open native browser from within a virtual machine on Mac

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Is there a way to open a browser window from within the vagrant vm? This is what it says:

```
$ open .
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
$ open http://localhost:3000
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

Since I'm in the vm on ubuntu, probably that open command doesn't work or doesn't exist I'm guessing. But is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: Be clear please. You mention OSX in the title, a Vagrant VM and an Ubuntu VM in the question. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I second @Tonny. Are you trying to open a web browser or a filesystem browser? And when you say native, do you mean Ubuntu-native (Vagrant VM guest OS native) or MacOSX-native (host OS native) browser?

Comment: By the way, it seems Ubuntu's `open(1)` is actually a link to `openvt(1)`, which apparently opens a *command* (such as a shell) in a new virtual terminal window. It's almost nothing like OS X's `open(1)` command, which does about the same thing as double-clicking an icon in the Finder (open directories in Finder, opens documents in their native editor, opens URLs in the default handler for that URL scheme). That "Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console" error is from Ubuntu's `open[vt]` command, not OS X's `open`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a rough equivalent of OS X's `open` command, but which opens things within the  Ubuntu environment instead of OSX, then you probably want `gnome-open` or `xdg-open`.

See also: [Linux equivalent command for "open" command on Mac/Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/38984/linux-equivalent-command-for-open-command-on-mac-windows)