# How do I open multiple files at once with Windows Powershell?

Tags: powershell

On MacOS I can use the "open" command to open multiple files by separating them with spaces, even with different filetypes.
Ex. `open [1.jpg] [2.jpg]`

How can I do the same on Windows Powershell?

I have tried using the start command, Invoke-Item, and the method described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/38975/windows-equivalent-command-for-open-command-on-mac) with space separated and comma separated files, but none seem to work.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't. What you can do is either use `Invoke-Item` multiple times for the different files, or you can use PowerShell's [pipelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.2) to pipe the input to the first positional parameter of the command, which in this case just happens to be the file path. Example: `"1.jpg", "2.jpg" | Invoke-Item`.

Comment: Is the goal to just open then? You could use semicolon like:  notepad file1.txt; notepad file2.txt on a single line. If you need them async then: start notepad file1.txt; start notepad file2.txt

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Both solutions work like a charm. Could you add the comment as a post so I can mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the semi-colon:

```
notepad test1.txt; notepad test2.txt
```

This will open the files one after the other.

Using start in combination with the semi-colon, you can open in parallel:

```
start notepad test1.txt; start notepad test2.txt
```

Comment: I think the intent is to open a given document - whatever its type - with whatever application is registered for it; hard-coding `notepad` won't do that. Note that `notepad` is a GUI-subsystem application and therefore _by default_ runs _asynchronously_, so there is no need for `start` (`Start-Process`).

Answer (score 0):

[Jesse](https://superuser.com/users/1135411/jesse) has provided the crucial pointer:

- Since [`Invoke-Item`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/invoke-item) - the PowerShell cmdlet that opens documents with their registered application analogous to `open` on macOS - only accepts a *single* document as an *argument*, you must provide the paths of *multiple* documents to open *via the pipeline*.
- While you *can* pass the paths as *strings* through the pipeline, there's a small *caveat*:

  - Because they bind to the `-Path` parameter, the strings are interpreted as [wildcard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) expressions, which causes problems with paths that contain `[` and `]`
- To avoid this problem, the `-LiteralPath` parameter must be bound, which is most easily done by using the output from [`Get-ChildItem`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) or [`Get-Item`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item), which *does* accept multiple paths *as arguments*:

```
Get-Item -LiteralPath [1.jpg], [2.jpg] | Invoke-Item # binds to -LiteralPath
```

If the wildcard issue is not in the picture, either of the following forms will do; note how with `Get-Item` quoting the arguments is optional in this simple case (but paths with spaces or other metacharacters would require them):

```
'1.jpg', '2.jpg' | Invoke-Item  # binds to -Path

# or

Get-Item 1.jpg, 2.jpg | Invoke-Item # -Path implied for Get-Item
```